# Given a 3-connected graph $G$, is there an edge $e$ so that both $G-e$ and $G/e$ are still 3-connected?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Let $G$ be a [3-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph) (simple) graph other than $K_4$. In [Diestel's "Graph Theory"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-53622-3) Section 3.2 we find

- **Lemma 3.2.2.** There is an edge $e$ so that $G\mathbin{\dot-}e$ is still 3-connected (where $G\mathbin{\dot-}e$ means deleting $e$ and supressing resulting vertices of degree 2).
- **Lemma 3.2.4.** There is an edge $e$ so that $G/e$ is still 3-connected (where $G/e$ means [contracting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction) $e$ and replacing resulting double edges by a single edge).

I wonder, can we always find an edge $e$ so that *both* $G\mathbin{\dot-}e$ and $G/e$ are still 3-connected? Is it true at least if $G$ is planar?

Comment: You can also create degree-2 vertices when you contract an edge.  For example, in a triangular prism, contracting an edge from a triangle creates a degree-2 vertex (after suppressing parallel edges).  In fact, the triangular prism is a counterexample, given your definitions of $G -e$ and $G / e$.  Maybe you also want to supress degree-2 vertices when contracting?

Comment: @TonyHuynh You are right, and supressing degree-2 vertices after a deletion can create double edges. So I think what I want is to "iteratively normalize" the graph after a deletion/contraction so as to not contain degree-2 vertices or double edges. Your answer provides sufficient counterexample still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**, this is false even in the planar case.  Let $G=W_n$ be a [wheel graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_graph) with $n \geq 6$.  Deleting any edge of the outercycle yields a fan graph, which is not $3$-connected.  On the other hand, contracting any edge which is not on the outercycle also yields a fan graph. Thus, there is no edge $e$ such that $G - e$ and $G / e$ are both $3$-connected.